# Symfony : adding standard constraint in a custom constraint

Tags: symfony, constraints

I'm trying to add in a custom constraint defined as defined [in the official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html), a built-in constraint (for instance, Url).

So basically, I've added to my validator class, in the validation method:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Url;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint): void
{
    [...]
    $this->context
        ->getValidator()
        ->inContext($this->context)
        ->validate($value, new Url());
}
```

as it seems possible in [this article](https://jolicode.com/blog/how-to-dynamically-validate-some-data-with-symfony-validator).

Unfortunately, it is not working. The violation is not added to the other of the constraint. I have no choice to replace the code by something less concise as :

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Url;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint): void
{
    [...]
    $urlConstraint = new Url();
    $violations = $this->context
        ->getValidator()
        ->validate($value, $urlConstraint);

    if (count($violations) !== 0) {
        $this->context
            ->buildViolation($urlConstraint->message)
            ->addViolation();
}
```

Is there any possibility to include the standard constraint to the custom one (without of course adding the constraint directly to the Entity class) ?

Comment: but why?
just annotate/attributes both the standard constraint and your callback constraint.

Answer (score 1):

In the example above, I didn't mention that the validation was placed in a specific validation group.
Because of that, the standard constraint wasn't triggered. It was necessary to attach the standard constraint to the default group:

```
$this->context
    ->getValidator()
    ->inContext($this->context)
    ->validate($value, new Url(), Constraint::DEFAULT_GROUP);
```

`Constraint::DEFAULT_GROUP` is equals to 'Default'.

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce the problem (Symfony 6.2), all violations are added. Perhaps the problem is something else. The code for compare:

```php
namespace App\Validator;

use Attribute;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

#[Attribute]
class MyConstraint extends Constraint
{
}
```

```php
namespace App\Validator;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Url;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class MyConstraintValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $this->context
            ->buildViolation('Not valid.')
            ->addViolation();

        $this->context
            ->getValidator()
            ->inContext($this->context)
            ->validate($value, new Url());
    }
}
```

```php
namespace App\Request;

use App\Validator\MyConstraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;

class YourRequest
{
    #[Email]
    #[MyConstraint]
    #[Length(exactly: 2)]
    public string $value;
}
```

In this case, 4 violations are displayed: Email, 'Not valid.', Url, Length.

Comment: Dear Vodevel, Thank you for your answer. I've finally found the solution => see the answer below.